Dismiss SFSafariViewController without animation on "Done" tap
After presenting SFSafariViewController modally, a user presses the "Done" button and the controller is dismissed with animation. If I implement the delegate and try to dismiss it without animation, it has no effect (still dismissed with animation):
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: webUrl)
vc.delegate = self
self.present(vc, animated: true)

extension MyCoolViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

If I try to dismiss the controller programmatically, it works just great and the animated flag is honored but it I try to do it in the safariViewControllerDidFinish, the animation is playing regardless.
Is it possible to override that behavior and dismiss the SFSafariViewController without animation when a user taps the "Done" button?

I've tried dismiss(_:), but it seems like it did not have any effect on dismiss style as normal. There is another approach, it's handling transitioningDelegate by yourself:
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: webUrl)
vc.transitioningDelegate = self
...

extension MyCoolViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        dismissed.view.alpha = 0
        return .none
    }
}

Output:

